# Mutating Gravatar

Tags: bug, gravatar

My gravatar has always been yellow, but as of about 10 minutes ago (~10PM EST) I noticed it had changed in the navigation bar.  And in my profile.  But my posts are still clinging to the yellow they know and love:

[image: Gravatar can't make up its mind]

Is this a bug with stackoverflow, or gravatar, or my eyesight?  Not very important, but the world doesn't feel right anymore without my yellow icon.